# Get Every Week's Start and End Date from List<DateTime> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have scenario user will give input **Start Date** and **End Date**. i make list of `DateTime` between that Date Range.

Now I have list of `DateTime` in a sequence let's say from 1st of this month to 30th of this month and i want to get start and end date of every week in a result set like:

```
WeekStartDate   WeekEndDate  
01/01/2015      04/01/2015
05/01/2015      11/01/2015
```

i have tried myself using linq to get the desired outcome, but i am unable to get my head around to get the desired output, here is my try:

```
var dating = from d in dates
             group d by new { d.Day, d.DayOfWeek,d.Date } into g
             where g.Key.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday || g.Key.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
             select g;
```

### EDIT:

i am now able to get week combination but it  not complete as it misses 1st week due Monday check because first date can be other than Monday day:

```
var dating = from d in dates
             let NextWeekDate = d.Date.AddDays(6)
             group d by new { d.Day, d.DayOfWeek, d.Date, NextWeekDate } into g
             where g.Key.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
             select new { 
                          StartWeekDate = g.Key.Date, 
                          EndWeekDate = g.Key.NextWeekDate 
                        };
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - you want the result to contain the 1. First date of the month 2. All sundays end times 3. All Monday start times. Am I right?

Comment: @MotiAzu I think he wants each week's start and end date in one pair.so the result should be list of those pairs.

Comment: @Selman22 you got it right, i need in pair start and end date of every week of given date range

Comment: By 21k you should know how this site works. Put your solution in as an answer, not edited into the question, and don't edit `[Solved]` into your title.

Comment: @Rawling i will add it as answer, i was expecting that someone may answer better than mine..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these two extension methods somewhere and these helped me to get the desired output:

```
public static DateTime NextDayOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
     int offsetDays = dayOfWeek - dt.DayOfWeek;
     return dt.AddDays(offsetDays > 0 ? offsetDays : offsetDays + 7).AtMidnight();
}
```

### NextDayOfWeek():

> > this return the next day of week from the current date, it can be used this way:

```
DateTime comingSunday = DateTime.Now.NextDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

and this one is for getting previous day in this week:

### PreviousDayOfWeek():

> > > > this return the previous day of week from the current date, it can be used this way:

```
public static DateTime PreviousOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
   int offsetDays = -(dt.DayOfWeek - dayOfWeek);
   return dt.AddDays(offsetDays).AtMidnight();
}
```

and it can be used like:

```
DateTime thisWeekMonday = DateTime.Now.PreviousDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

and here is my messy query which i refactored and found that there is no need to group:

```
var dating = from d in dates
             let PreviousDate = d.PreviousOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday)
             let NextWeekDate = d.NextDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday)
             group d by new 
                       { 
                         d.Day, 
                         d.DayOfWeek, 
                         d.Date, 
                         NextWeekDate 
                       } into g
             where g.Key.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
             select new 
                   { 
                     StartWeekDate = g.Key.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday ? g.Key.Date.PreviousOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday) : g.Key.Date, 
                      EndWeekDate = g.Key.NextWeekDate 
                   };
```

Refactored One:

```
var dating22 = (from d in dates
               where d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
               select new 
               { 
                 StartWeekDate = d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday ? d.Date.PreviousOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday) : d.Date, 
                 EndWeekDate = d.NextDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday) 
               }).Distinct();
```

If we want to get from the start date passed to onward then:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 28);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2015, 2, 10);

var dates = startDate.Range(endDate);

var fromStartDateToEndDate = )from d in dates
                             where d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
                             select new 
                                   { 
                                      StartWeekDate = d.Date, 
                                      EndWeekDate = d.Date.NextDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday) 
                                   }).Distinct();
```

If we want it to start from the Monday of the start date as start date can be other than Monday, so we need to do from monday if then:

```
var fromStartingWeekOfStartDateRefactored = (from d in dates
                                            where d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
                                            select new 
                                                 { 
                                                   StartWeekDate = d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday ? d.Date.PreviousOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday) : d.Date, 
                                                   EndWeekDate = d.NextDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday) 
                                                  }).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Code is self-explanatory; I've used a `Tuple<>` as the representative of a week.

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-26);
var endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

var weeks = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>();
for (var date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    if (date == startDate)
    {
        // find the next Sunday 
        var start = (int)date.DayOfWeek;
        var target = (int)DayOfWeek.Sunday;
        if (target < start)
            target += 7;
        weeks.Add(Tuple.Create(date, date.AddDays(target - start)));
    }
    else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        weeks.Add(Tuple.Create(date, date.AddDays(6)));
    }
}
```

Note that if the first date is a Sunday (e.g. 4 Jan 2015), the first week starts and ends on that day.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a collection of dates which start at a variable point in a month and you want a list of the starts and ends of the weeks. @Selman22 is on the right track, but you can't add 6 days to the 1st of january to get the next sunday.
This is similar but will handle the first week case properly:

```
int firstDay = dates.Min(x => x).Day;
var dating = from d in dates
             where d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday || d.Day == firstDay
                select new
                {
                    StartDate = d,
                    EndDate = d.AddDays(
                        Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
                                  .First(n => d.AddDays(n).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
                };
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/// <summary>
/// Customized class for the Date Range Container...
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class WeekRange
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Range { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Week { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Month { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Year { get; set; }
}




         /// <summary>
        /// Get the Week Range for the Given Date Range.....
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="startDate"></param>
        /// <param name="endDate"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<WeekRange> WeekDays(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            DateTime startDateToCheck = startDate;
            DateTime dateToCheck = startDate;
            DateTime dateRangeBegin = dateToCheck;
            DateTime dateRangeEnd = endDate;

            List<WeekRange> weekRangeList = new List<WeekRange>();
            WeekRange weekRange = new WeekRange();

            while ((startDateToCheck.Year <= endDate.Year) && (startDateToCheck.Month <= endDate.Month) && dateToCheck <= endDate)
            {
                int week = 0;

                while (startDateToCheck.Month == dateToCheck.Month && dateToCheck <= endDate)
                {
                    week = week + 1;
                    dateRangeBegin = dateToCheck.AddDays(-(int)dateToCheck.DayOfWeek);
                    dateRangeEnd = dateToCheck.AddDays(6 - (int)dateToCheck.DayOfWeek);

                    if ((dateRangeBegin.Date < dateToCheck) && (dateRangeBegin.Date.Month != dateToCheck.Month))
                    {
                        dateRangeBegin = new DateTime(dateToCheck.Year, dateToCheck.Month, dateToCheck.Day);
                    }

                    if ((dateRangeEnd.Date > dateToCheck) && (dateRangeEnd.Date.Month != dateToCheck.Month))
                    {
                        DateTime dtTo = new DateTime(dateToCheck.Year, dateToCheck.Month, 1);
                        dtTo = dtTo.AddMonths(1);
                        dateRangeEnd = dtTo.AddDays(-(dtTo.Day));
                    }
                    if (dateRangeEnd.Date > endDate)
                    {
                        dateRangeEnd = new DateTime(dateRangeEnd.Year, dateRangeEnd.Month, endDate.Day);
                    }
                    weekRange = new WeekRange
                    {
                        StartDate = dateRangeBegin.ToShortDateString(),
                        EndDate = dateRangeEnd.ToShortDateString(),
                        Range = dateRangeBegin.Date.ToShortDateString() + '-' + dateRangeEnd.Date.ToShortDateString(),
                        Month = dateToCheck.Month,
                        Year = dateToCheck.Year,
                        Week = week
                    };
                    weekRangeList.Add(weekRange);
                    dateToCheck = dateRangeEnd.AddDays(1);
                }
                startDateToCheck = startDateToCheck.AddMonths(1);
            }
            return weekRangeList;
        }
```

The code takes input (Year,Month) : Let us say (2014,08) Aug-2014. Now running the code we are adding the week range values to the week-range object.

The output would appear as a list of dates , One of the sample values would be as below :-

EndDate :- 08/02/2014
Month   :- 8
Range   :- 08/01/2014-08/02/2014
Start Date :- 08/01/2014
Week :- 1
Year :- 2014

Comment: add some explanation to your answer.?

Comment: The code above will give the result set in the form of weeks with date range embedded in it. Hope it helps .... :)

Comment: instead of putting comment, edit your answer, then add explanation?